# How to repartition CassandraRDD in Apache Spark

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-spark, datastax-java-driver, rdd

I am using **Three Node Cassandra** cluster with **Six Spark Workers**, each has **1 Core** and **2GB RAM**.
Using Spark Application, I am trying to fetch entire data from Cassandra Table which has more than 300k rows and trying to do some aggregation.

But it is taking a lots of time to fetch data from Cassandra. I also went through Spark UI, I have seen that **Spark stage has 3 partition**, in which two are executing very fast (within seconds) but third one taking long time (7 min).

And I also tried to repartition CassandraRDD to increase number of tasks and distribute tasks to all six workers but didn't find out any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To adjust the number of tasks created by the CassandraRDD you need to adjust the spark.cassandra.input.split.size. This determines how many actual Spark Partitions will be made.

```
spark.cassandra.input.split.size    approx number of Cassandra partitions in a Spark partition  100000
```

Note that this controls the number of C* partitions, not C* rows in a spark partition. It is also an estimate so you can't be guaranteed that this exact number of tokens will be in a spark Partition.

If you continue to see some Partitions acting slower than others I would investigate the node's health for that Partition, and check for hotspots.

Comment: I have set this --conf spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb=32, still all my data of around 250 mb is loaded in one executor (~4 million records)

Comment: please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775696/repartitioning-of-dataframe-in-spark-does-not-work