# Repartitioning of dataframe in spark does not work

Tags: apache-spark

I have a cassandra database with large numbers of records ~4 million. I have 3 slave machines and one driver. I want to load this data in spark memory and do processing of it. When I do the following it reads all the data in one slave machine(300 mb out of 6 Gb) and all other slave machines memory is unused. I did a reparition on the dataframe into 3 but still the data is there on one machine. Because of this it takes a lot of time to process data since every job is executed on one machine. This is what I am doing

```
val tabledf = _sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(Map( "table" -> "events", "keyspace" -> "sams")).load
        tabledf.registerTempTable("tempdf");
        _sqlContext.cacheTable("tempdf");
val rdd = _sqlContext.sql(query);   
val partitionedRdd = rdd.repartition(3)
        val count = partitionedRdd.count.toInt
```

When I do some operations on partitionedRdd it is executed only on one machine since all data is present on one machine only

UPDATE
I am using this in the configuration --conf spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb=32, still all my data is loaded into one executor

[image]

Update
I am using spark version 1.4 and spark cassandra connector version 1.4 released

Comment: Are you sure your configuration is correct and you don't have a `val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]")` somewhere?

Comment: No, I am running in cluster mode with web UI showing 3 slave machines. Also I am running with this configuration spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb=67108864

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583249/apache-spark-taking-5-to-6-minutes-for-simple-count-of-1-billon-rows-from-cassan, this is why I am using 67108864

Comment: Oh, sorry - it's morning and I didn't see the `rdd.repartition`. I think you want to increase the number of partitions. I don't know which type of instances your slaves are, but I'm guessing that they have multiple compute units. The number of partitions (which you have currently set to 3) should be at least `numberOfSlaves*numberOfComputeUnitsOnEachSlave` in order for you to utilize the cluster optimally.

Comment: I have dual core 8 gb machines on slave. Is the number of Computer Units equal to the number of cores?

Comment: Sometimes but not always. If you look at http://www.ec2instances.info/ you will see that most Amazon instances types have many more compute units than cores. But if I were you, I would simply increase the number of partitions to say 50 to see if this solves your problem. If it does, you can then experiment with the partitions. Note that having many partitions is a good thing - not a bad thing. You should only be worried about too many partitions if each of your tasks takes only a second or so to complete.

Comment: Is there a way wherein I can define the partitions at the time of data loading rather than after data is loaded and then repartitioning it?

Comment: I updated the spark cassandra connector and gave this configuration spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb=32 still one one executor has all the records in memory

Answer (score 0):

If "Query" only accesses a single C* partition key you will only get a single task because we don't have a way (yet) of automatically getting a single cassandra partition in parallel. If you are accessing multiple C* partitions then try futher shrinking the input split_size in mb.

Comment: Yes i am trying with a single partition key. I tried repartioning the dataframe after its loaded in memory with caching but that didnt helped.

Comment: Is there a way wherein i can spread out the data to other machines or i can index on a particular column so that i can have range query on that column.

Comment: To parallelism the single query you'll need to know the data in the partition and do parallel range queries

Comment: If single partition key creates a single partition then i am not wrong if i say 10 partition key will create 10 partition. Then why so we need to have spark.xassandra.input.split.size_in_mb configuratuon variable

Comment: Also is it documented somewhere that single partition key will create only a single partition in spark

Comment: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md#why-is-my-job-running-on-a-single-executor-why-am-i-not-seeing-any-parallelism

Comment: "In" Clauses also will share a single partition.

Comment: What is exactly a C* partition key, is it a clustering key?